# Safari 7.0.4 doesn't remember my login status. "Remember me" not working (OS X 10.9.3)

Tags: safari, login, bug

The problem is that I must press "log in"/"sign in" button on most web-services again and again per day. All login/passwords are stored successfuly but the feature which is often called "remember me" doesn't works. What could be the reason for this bug?
In before: the cookies are enabled.

UPD> I must say that I have an iPhone and an iPad with enabled keychain sharing via iCloud but the problem I have on the mac never happens on my devices. Maybe it will helps.

Comment: What are your cookie settings?

Comment: @MaxRied as I said `In before: the cookies are enabled.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I've finally fixed the bug.

Follow these steps:

1. go to Disk utility
2. select your disk on the left list
3. press "Repair Disk Permissions" on the right view

here is the screenshot
http://monosnap.com/image/5aVsTd4te6SD6Tp1UuxjyIi3ov1xHs.png

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score -1):

My best recommendation is to use Chrome on Mac OS. If you have a google account it syncs all your passwords and more across all devices. I'm an apple guy across the board and I use chrome for web browsing for exactly the issues you mentioned.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it would make an alright comment.

Comment: The chrome works perfectly indeed. But I hate it for the unoptimized power usage which is critical on the laptop