# Safari will not "Remember Me" on Facebook

Tags: safari, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, facebook

My question is very similar to this question:

[Safari 7.0.4 doesn't remember my login status. "Remember me" not working (OS X 10.9.3)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134612/safari-7-0-4-doesnt-remember-my-login-status-remember-me-not-working-os-x-1)

Except it differs in 3 key ways:

1. The solution did not work for me This occurs ONLY on Facebook.com;
   reddit, twitter, netflix, etc.'s "remember me" function works fine.
2. The erasure of the cookies does not occur during restart of the
   browser. In fact, I can restart safari and still be logged in.
3. The
   erasure happens when I put the computer to sleep and wake it up
   again.

I have confirmed that the cookies are being reset. The cookie list is entirely different on wake, and I am booted out of Facebook.

The curious thing is that it only occurs for Facebook. This is really annoying though, and my next resort will be a full reinstall.

Extra info:

Newest model Retina MacBook Pro (August 2014) running OS X 10.9.4
Safari 7.0.6

**EDIT**

It seems to have been resolved for now, with a "Repair Disk Permissions" from Disk Utility, although I suspect it will occur again.

**EDIT**

This is a long time after I asked the question, however I did eventually figure it out. It turns out that I had connected my Skype to my Facebook account, and that was somehow triggering a logout every time I opened Skype (that's why it seemed so random). So solution for anybody who's having this problem: just disconnect Skype and Facebook. Never had this issue again.

Answer (score -1):

add site to cookies/cache approved list in browser settings

Comment: Could you expand on exactly how to achieve this?

Comment: Safari is set to accept cookies from every site.